# How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, search

When I use the `re.search()` function to find matches in a block of text, the program exits once it finds the first match in the block of text.

How do I do this repeatedly where the program doesn't stop until ALL matches have been found? Is there a separate function to do this?

Comment: [Recursive REs](http://web.archive.org/web/20030206032122/http://www.puffinry.freeserve.co.uk/regex-extension.html) are a different beast. You want to repeat the search.

Answer (score 864, accepted):

Use `re.findall` or `re.finditer` instead.

[`re.findall(pattern, string)`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a list of matching strings.

[`re.finditer(pattern, string)`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.finditer) returns an iterator over [`MatchObject`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) objects.

**Example:**

```
re.findall( r'all (.*?) are', 'all cats are smarter than dogs, all dogs are dumber than cats')
# Output: ['cats', 'dogs']

[x.group() for x in re.finditer( r'all (.*?) are', 'all cats are smarter than dogs, all dogs are dumber than cats')]
# Output: ['all cats are', 'all dogs are']
```

Comment: `finditer` was what I was looking for. I'm surprised that one returns Match objects and the other strings. I was expecting to use a `match_all` or `match_iter` function.

Comment: DISCLAIMER: those will find only **non-overlapping** matches

Comment: @AntoineLizée, how does one find iterations WITH overlap?

Comment: @Raksha - Use `re.search` in a loop. It'll return a `Match` object. You'll want to pass in `Match.start() + 1` as the `pos` argument for `re.search` for the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: If the match contains more than one group, `findall` will return a list of matching tuples, not a list of matching strings.

Comment: Here's an example to help visualizing:  `re.findall( r'all (.*?) are', 'all cats are smarter than dogs, all dogs are dumber than cats')` (output: `['cats', 'dogs']`)

Comment: findall is not useful for named groups.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare but `re.search()` doesn't have a `pos` argument

Comment: @vonspotz `re.search` doesn't but `pattern.search` does. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77830224/19123103) for an implementation. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Another method (a bit in keeping with OP's initial spirit albeit 13 years later) is to compile the pattern and call `search()` on the compiled pattern and move along the pattern. This is a bit verbose but if you hate lookahead etc., then you can use the following function.

```py
def find_all_matches(pattern, string):
    pat = re.compile(pattern)
    pos = 0
    out = []
    while (match := pat.search(string, pos)) is not None:
        pos = match.start() + 1
        out.append(match[1])
    return out

find_all_matches(r'all (.*?) are', 'all cats are smarter than dogs, all dogs are dumber than cats')
# ['cats', 'dogs']
```

This works for overlapping matches too:

```py
find_all_matches(r'(\w\w)', "hello")  # ['he', 'el', 'll', 'lo']
```