# Get the string within brackets in Python

Tags: python, regex, brackets

I have a sample string `<alpha.Customer[cus_Y4o9qMEZAugtnW] active_card=<alpha.AlphaObject[card] ...>, created=1324336085, description='Customer for My Test App', livemode=False>`

I only want the value `cus_Y4o9qMEZAugtnW` and NOT `card` (which is inside another `[]`)

How could I do it in easiest possible way in Python?
Maybe by using RegEx (which I am not good at)?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

How about:

```
import re

s = "alpha.Customer[cus_Y4o9qMEZAugtnW] ..."
m = re.search(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]", s)
print m.group(1)
```

For me this prints:

```
cus_Y4o9qMEZAugtnW
```

Note that the call to `re.search(...)` finds the first match to the regular expression, so it doesn't find the `[card]` unless you repeat the search a second time.

**Edit:** The [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) here is a python [raw string literal](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), which basically means the backslashes are not treated as special characters and are passed through to the `re.search()` method unchanged. The [parts](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) of the regular expression are:

1. `\[` matches a literal `[` character
2. `(` begins a new group
3. `[A-Za-z0-9_]` is a character set matching any letter (capital or lower case), digit or underscore
4. `+` matches the preceding element (the character set) one or more times.
5. `)` ends the group
6. `\]` matches a literal `]` character

**Edit:** As D K has pointed out, the regular expression could be simplified to:

```
m = re.search(r"\[(\w+)\]", s)
```

since the `\w` is a special sequence which means the same thing as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` depending on the `re.LOCALE` and `re.UNICODE` settings.

Comment: could you please explain your answer the regex part, so that i donot have to ask again for similar type of problems. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my answer with an explanation of the regular expression and links to the python regular expression documentation.

Comment: Why not replace `[A-Za-z0-9_]` with `\w`?

Comment: Yes, you could replace `[A-Za-z0-9_]` with `\w`.

Comment: how could plus and minus signs '+' and '-' be added to character sets?
 i tried using [A-Za-z0-9_\+\-] but it didnt work!!

Comment: @user3015703 In a character set you don't need to escape special characters, except for '-' or ']'. To include a dash you can either precede it with a slash, or make it the first or last character in the set. So using '[A-Za-z0-9_+-]' should work. See the [Python regular expression syntax documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: you can use `re.findall(r"\{{([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\}}", s)` to find all the occurrences.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if the expression in the brackets has a `.` in it. Any ideas for how to make that work?

Answer (score 25):

You could use [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to do this.

```
s = "<alpha.Customer[cus_Y4o9qMEZAugtnW] active_card=<alpha.AlphaObject[card]\
 ...>, created=1324336085, description='Customer for My Test App',\
 livemode=False>"
val = s.split('[', 1)[1].split(']')[0]
```

Then we have:

```
>>> val
'cus_Y4o9qMEZAugtnW'
```

Comment: Yeah, it depends on how much messy the strings are, but a split could work here too..

Comment: though it wont effect much, but which of the two using regex/split is more efficient. Also could you please explain your splitting part. Thanks.

Comment: @user993563 Have a look at the link to `str.split` in the answer for examples. Briefly, the first `split` in the solution returns a list of length two; the first element is the substring before the first `[`, the second is the substring after `]`. As for performance, you should measure that to find out (look at [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html)). If you plan to do the value extraction several times in one run of the program and decide to use regular expressions, you might want to [`compile`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.compile) the regex.

Comment: @user993563 Note that your request for the "easiest possible way in python" may be at odds with the performance consideration. I chose to use `split` because I felt that reflected your request for "easiest".

Comment: simple to understand, better than re.

Answer (score 20):

This should do the job:

```
re.match(r"[^[]*\[([^]]*)\]", yourstring).groups()[0]
```

Comment: I guess this was more than the OP needed since his case only needed alphanumerics, but this did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: This would be really slow as we are checking a llllllotttt of stuff. therefore I would rather suggest using "\[(.*?)\]", follow my answer below if the brackets aren't shown here properly.

Answer (score 8):

```
your_string = "lnfgbdgfi343456dsfidf[my data] ljfbgns47647jfbgfjbgskj"
your_string[your_string.find("[")+1 : your_string.find("]")]
```

courtesy: [Regular expression to return text between parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894069/regular-expression-to-return-text-between-parenthesis)

Comment: Works only if no other brackets presented.

Comment: @АлександрЗахаров yes. we can only use this method for simple cases only.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use

```
re.findall(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]", string)
```

if there are many occurrences that you would like to find.

See also for more info:
[How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python)

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
import re

s = re.search(r"\[.*?]", string)
if s:
    print(s.group(0))
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this ? Example illusrated using a file:

```
f = open('abc.log','r')
content = f.readlines()
for line in content:
    m = re.search(r"\[(.*?)\]", line)
    print m.group(1)
```

Hope this helps:

```
Magic regex : \[(.*?)\]
```

Explanation:

`\[` : `[` is a meta char and needs to be escaped if you want to match it literally.

`(.*?)` : match everything in a non-greedy way and capture it.

`\]` : `]` is a meta char and needs to be escaped if you want to match it literally.

Answer (score 1):

This snippet should work too, but it will return any text enclosed within "[]"

```
re.findall(r"\[([a-zA-Z0-9 ._]*)\]", your_text)
```