# Python Parsing with a Variable Name and Square Brackets

Tags: python, regex, square-bracket

I have a file named item.dat containing bracketed keywords:

```
[ITEM1]
banana
peach
apple
orange
grapes
[END]
[ITEM3]
tennis
bowling
[END]
........
```

I want to the lines between the bracketed keywords to be processed.  The variable wil contain the bracketed lines I want to extract.  The problem is how do I perform a line comparison for "[ItemName]"?

```
del item[:]
ItemName = "ITEM3"
with open('item.dat') as input_data:
    for line in input_data:
        if line.strip() == "\[ItemName\]":   # the problematic line
            break
    for line in input_data:  # This keeps reading the file
        if line.strip() == '[END]':
            break
        print line
        item.append(line)
```

Comment: The variable ItemName will be my search string.  In this case, ItemName is set to ITEM3.  Next time, I may set it to say ITEM100.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^\[(?!END).*]
```

---

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/oK4qQ5/2)

Explaining:

```
^\[          # starts with a '[' character
(?!END)      # don't match 'END'
.*]$         # take all till the end ']' character
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the question that you have asked can be answered using the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8569258/5091348) with only slight modifications. As the linked answer is so thorough, I will not repeat the answer, but if for some reason that does not work, let me know and I can provide some alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I really understand the question, but a simple way of extracting the bracketed values is this:

```
items = []
variables = []

with open('item.dat') as input_data:
    for line in input_data:
        line = line.strip()
        if line and line[0] == '[' and line[-1] == ']':
            variables.append(line)
        else:
            items.append(line)
```

Printing the two lists using the data provided results in:

```
variables = ['[ITEM1]', '[END]', '[ITEM3]', '[END]']
items = ['banana', 'peach', 'apple', 'orange', 'grapes', 'tennis', 'bowling']
```