# How to find a number enclosed in square brackets followed by a string?

Tags: python, python-re

I am trying to get the numbers enclosed in square brackets that are preceded by a string. The search should be based on the phonenumber and not the first [] square brackets.

```
mystring = 'my name is raj and my phoneNumber [12343567890] , pincode[123]'
expected=1234567890
```

I tried the following but it is not fetching the right values

```
re.search(r'^phoneNumber \[\s*\+?(-?\d+)\s*\]', mystring ).group(0)
```

can anyone help me with the code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the string within brackets in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569201/get-the-string-within-brackets-in-python)

Comment: @sushanth tried it but it is not working for my case. that is why i added this qn

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `r'^phoneNumber \[\s*\+?(-?\d+)\s*\]'`, what do you think the `^` means? Do you see how this interferes with the intended regex search? (Hint: is the desired text at the start of the string?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this answer [1] and add the string `phoneNumber` to the regex:

```
import re

s = "my name is raj and my phoneNumber [12343567890] , pincode[123]"
m = re.search(r"phoneNumber \[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]", s) 
print(m.group(1))
```

[1] [Get the string within brackets in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569201/get-the-string-within-brackets-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get the numbers enclosed in a square brackets that is preceded by a string.

Try the below (no regexp)

```
mystring = 'my name is raj and my phoneNumber [12343567890] , pincode[123]'
left = mystring.find('[')
right = mystring.find(']')
num = mystring[left + 1:right]
print(num)
```

output

```
12343567890
```

Comment: thanks for the help but it will not work if the phone number is after the pincode. it will retrieve the first number pattern enclosed in a []

Comment: Please edit your question so that this requirement is in it. You did not specify this originally.

Comment: No it will not work. Extend the question and explain more about the possible input.