# Get the string between [ brackets and special characters in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a really similar question to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8569201/get-the-string-within-brackets-in-python).

And i really wonder why my restult is: `NaN`.

I have a dataframe which this column:

```
Action
Player[J♡, K♧] won the $5.40 main pot with a Straight
Player [5, 2] won the $21.00 main pot with a flush
```

and I want to built a new column with the cards, who got played:

```
[J♡, K♧]
[5, 2]
```

or even:

```
[J, K]
[5, 2]
```

However when I play around on [regex](https://regex101.com/) and i use:
`dfpot['cards'] = dfpot['Action'].str.extract(r'\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]', expand=False)`

I only got `NaN`.

Comment: Perhaps add them to the character class with a comma and a space `\[([A-Za-z0-9_♤♡♢♧, ]+)\]`

Comment: What about `df['Action'].str.extract(r'\[([^][]+)]', expand=False).str.findall(r'[A-Za-z0-9]+')`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird that was the problem, I had to include the special characters as well :)

Comment: You might make it a bit more specific `\[([A-Za-z0-9_][♤♡♢♧]?,\s*[A-Za-z0-9_][♤♡♢♧]?)\]` https://regex101.com/r/LjHP4O/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the characters to the character class in the capture group as in your pattern `\[([A-Za-z0-9_♤♡♢♧, ]+)\]` or make the pattern a bit more specific:

```
\[([A-Za-z0-9_][♤♡♢♧]?,\s*[A-Za-z0-9_][♤♡♢♧]?)]
```

The pattern matches:

- `\[` Match `[`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[A-Za-z0-9_]` Match one of the listed charss
  - `[♤♡♢♧]?` Optionally match one of the listed chars
  - `,\s*[A-Za-z0-9_][♤♡♢♧]?` Match a comma and the same logic as before the comma
- `)` Close group 1
- `]` Match `]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hi3PV6/1)

For example

```
import pandas as pd

dfpot = pd.DataFrame({'Action':['Player[J♡, K♧] won the $5.40 main pot with a Straight', 'Player [5, 2] won the $21.00 main pot with a flush']})
dfpot['cards'] = dfpot['Action'].str.extract(r'\[([A-Za-z0-9_][♤♡♢♧]?,\s*[A-Za-z0-9_][♤♡♢♧]?)]', expand=False)
print(dfpot)
```

Output

```
                                              Action   cards
0  Player[J♡, K♧] won the $5.40 main pot with a S...  J♡, K♧
1  Player [5, 2] won the $21.00 main pot with a f...    5, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pattern (I assumed that you use `()` in the text instead `[]`, as was posted in regex demo):

```
\([^,]+,[^\)]+\)
```

Explanation:

`\(` - match `(` literally

`[^,]+` - match one ore more character other than `,`

`,` - match `,` literally

`[^\)]+` - match one or more characters other than `)`

`\)` - match `)` literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/S7ULPR/1)

Comment: for me this leads to the error: ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups, the comment above solved the error, I had to include special characters, thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Use

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Action':['Player[J♡, K♧] won the $5.40 main pot with a Straight', 'Player [5, 2] won the $21.00 main pot with a flush']})
>>> df['cards'] = df['Action'].str.findall(r'(\w+)(?=[^][]*])')
>>> df
                                              Action   cards
0  Player[J♡, K♧] won the $5.40 main pot with a S...  [J, K]
1  Player [5, 2] won the $21.00 main pot with a f...  [5, 2]
>>>
```

**Regex**: `(\w+)(?=[^][]*])`

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^][]*                   any character except: ']', '[' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]                        ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```