# How to repeatedly capture a group?

Tags: regex

Suppose I have the following string

```
Bimkingo Clasico Prom 135g LON 49835 Gansito ME 5p 250g MTA MLA 49860 Wonder
```

I want to extract only tokens that don't contain numbers or only upper case letters.

The output should be

```
Bimkingo Clasico Prom Gansito Wonder
```

This doesn't seem to work: `\b(([a-zA-Z]+)+)\b`.

Comment: Please post what you expect the output to be for the string you provided.

Comment: Syntax highlighter seems to recognize the words you want.

Comment: (([a-zA-Z]+)+) seems strange, mb you meant ([a-zA-Z]+) ?

Comment: @AlexanderDavydov that will capture only Bimkingo.

Comment: @MadPhysicist you are right. I noticed that too, but unfortunately I don't have access to the syntax highlighting source code :p

Comment: I bet it doesn't use regex.

Comment: I think you need a regex which captures a word with mandatory digits in it. Then you capture triples: words without digits (the one you want), bracketed with optional words with digits, which you discard.

Comment: You can iterate over all matches of the \b([a-zA-Z]+)\b : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex `(\b[a-zA-Z]+[a-z]+\b)` should work as expected, for the output example in OP's post and other edge cases:

```js
var string = 'Bimkingo Clasico Prom 135g LON 49835 Gansito ME 5p 250g MTA MLA 49860 Wonder';
var regexp = /(\b[a-zA-Z]+[a-z]+\b)+/g;
var matches = string.match(regexp);
var output = "Bimkingo Clasico Prom Gansito Wonder";
console.log('Matches test output provided by OP "' + output + '":');
console.log(output === matches.join(' '), '\n');
console.log(''); // new line

// Cases not contained in OP's example output string...
var string = 'mArceLino marcelino';
console.log('Also matches all lowercase and uppercase mid word "' + string + '":', '\n');
var matches = string.match(regexp);
console.log(matches.length === 2);
console.log(''); // new line

var string = 'MARCEL1N0 MARCELINO11';
console.log('Excludes all uppercase with number mix "' + string + '":');
var matches = string.match(regexp);
console.log(matches === null);
```

The accepted answer by "krzyk" matches the output OP posted, but fails to "*extract only tokens that don't contain numbers or only upper case letters*" in edge cases not represented by OP's example output. Run the code snippet above for a better representation of the issue.

Regex explanation:

```
( --> // start capture
  \b --> // match start of word
  [a-zA-Z]+ --> // match one or more lowercase and uppercase letters 
  [a-z]+ --> // match one or more lowercase only
  \b --> // match end of word
) --> // end capture
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
(\b[A-Z]?[a-z]+\b)+
```

And retrieve all the groups from your regexp library (as there is no way to gave it in a single group) and join them with spaces.

Test case: https://regex101.com/r/hY2fM8/1

Comment: ah, so the key is the ```g``` global option?

Comment: how do I create the g option in a regex expression though?

Comment: never mind, you also said to retrieve the groups from regexp library.

Comment: This answer fails to "*extract only tokens that don't contain numbers or only upper case letters*" in edge cases not represented by OP's example output. See my answer for a more elaborate explanation.