# Python re find all combinations print as string

Tags: python, regex

Using Python regular expressions how can I find all instances of a combination and print each one on a new line?

Example:

```
import re

x = "a=123,b=123,c=123,d=123,a=456,b=456...etc"
y = re.search('a=(.*?),', x)
print(y)
```

Trying to get:

```
123
456
```

Comment: Have you read the `re` documentation? It has examples of how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python)

Comment: Or better yet, google, and then you find the above link.

Comment: @JSimonsen do you want to use regex for any particular reason ? findall is much more easier

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan Essentially pulling info from Logs and displaying just the parts I want to see.  Just looking for a clean way to do that and present it

Comment: re.findall() should probably be enough I guess as Ajax1234 answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The regular expression

First of all, your regular expression is incorrect. You're matching `a=` followed by any number of characters. This will match the entire string in one go because `*` is mostly greedy. Instead, you're trying to find any number of letters, an equal sign, and then any number of digits.

```
[A-Za-z]+=(\d+)  Regular Expression
        +        At least one
[A-Za-z]         (English) letter
         =       An equals sign
          (   )  Group 1
             +   At least one
           \d    digit
```

Also, use `re.findall` not `re.search`.

Then, doing `re.findall(r"[A-Za-z]+=(\d+)", x)` will give the list of strings, which you can print, parse, whatever.

Also, there might be a better way of doing this: if the data is exactly as you format it, you can just use regular string operations:

```
a = "a=123,b=456,c=789"
b = a.split(",") # gets ["a=123", "b=456", "c=789"]
c = [E.split("=") for E in b] # gets [["a", "123"], ["b", "456"], ["c", "789"]]
```

Then, if you want to turn this into a dictionary, you can use `dict(c)`. If you want to print the values, do `for E in c: print(E[1])`. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `re.findall`:

```
import re
x = "a=123,b=123,c=123,d=123,a=456,b=456...etc"
final_data = re.findall("(?<=a\=)\d+", x)
for i in final_data:
   print(i)
```

Output:

```
123
456
```

This regular expression utilizes a positive look behind to make sure that the digits are part of the `a=` expression:

`\d+`: matches all digits until non-numeric character is found (in this case the start of the next expression).

`(?<=a\=)`: searches for `a=` assignment part of expression and acts as anchor for `\d+` regex.

Comment: I'd recommend you explain the regular expression for those (including me) who might not understand it / are new to regex

Comment: @HyperNeutrino thank you for your suggestion. Please see my recent edit.