# Python regex preference if multiple matches

Tags: python, regex

I am searching for city names in a string:

```
mystring = 'SDM\Austin'
city_search = r'(SD|Austin)'
mo_city = re.search(city_search,mystring,re.IGNORECASE)
city = mo_city.group(1)
print(city)
```

This will return city as 'SD'.

Is there a way to make 'Austin' the preference?

Switching the order to (Austin|SD) doesn't work.

The answer is the same as [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python), but the use case is a little different since one match is preferred.

Comment: Switch the order of the options `(Austin|SD)`. Regex will stop at the first match. Otherwise, you can use the `all()` method.

Comment: Have you tried swapping `SD` and `Austin` in the regex?

Comment: I did try that and it didn't work. Sorry I should have mentioned... updating.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a bigger sample of the data you are parsing.

Comment: I did show the data that I'm parsing. It's "mystring"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python). You're using `search`, you need to use `findall` or `finditer`

Comment: @sparrow there must be a wider application to this because if you only ever want to extract `"Austin"` from `mysting` and assign this to `city`, why not just replace everything with: `city = "Austin"`?

Comment: @JoeIddon good point. In the data sometimes I get "SD" which is the city of San Diego so I want to return that, but it also gives false positives so I need to avoid it if I see the name of a full city. It looks like I'll need to go with finall or finditer and code in some logic.

Comment: @sparrow I wrote an answer explaining how if you want to use this `regex`, you must use `re.findall`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `re.search`, instead use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) which `returns` a `lists` of *all* `matches`.

So if you modify your code to:

```
mystring = 'SDM\Austin'
city_search = r'(SD|Austin)'
mo_city = re.findall(city_search,mystring,re.IGNORECASE)
city = mo_city[1]
print(city)
```

it will work find, outputting:

```
Austin
```

---

So, `mo_city` is a `list`: `['SD', 'Austin']` and since we want to `assign` the second `element` (`Austin`) to `city`, we take index `1` with `mo_city[1]`.

Comment: The nice thing about that approach is that I can list the things to search for in order of preference and assign the first match.

Answer (score 1):

### Brief

You already have a great answer here (using `findall` instead of `search` with regex). This is another alternative (without using regex) that checks a string against a list of strings and returns matches. Based on the sample code you provided, this should work for you and is probably easier than the regex method.

### Code

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/DhjEfy)

```
list = ['SD', 'Austin']
s = 'SDM\Austin'
for l in list:
    if l in s:
        print '"{}" exists in "{}"'.format(l, s);
```