# Python - Parsing JSON formatted text file with regex

Tags: python, json, regex, python-2.7

I have a text file formatted like a JSON file however everything is on a single line (could be a MongoDB File). Could someone please point me in the direction of how I could extract values using a Python regex method please?

The text shows up like this:

```
{"d":{"__type":"WikiFileNodeContent:http:\/\/samplesite.com.‌​au\/ns\/business\/wi‌​ki","author":null,"d‌​escription":null,"fi‌​leAssetId":"034b9317‌​-60d9-45c2-b6d6-0f24‌​b59e1991","filename"‌​:"Reports.pdf"},"cre‌​atedBy":1531,"create‌​dByUsername":"John Cash","icon":"\/Assets10.37.5.0\/pix\/16x16\/page_white_acro‌​bat.png","id":3041,"‌​inheritedPermissions‌​":false,"name":"map"‌​,"permissions":[23,8‌​7,35,49,65],"type":3‌​,"viewLevel":2},{"__‌​type":"WikiNode:http‌​:\/\/samplesite.com.‌​au\/ns\/business\/wi‌​ki","children":[],"c‌​ontent":
```

I am wanting to get the "fileAssetId" and filename". Ive tried to load the like with Pythons JSON module but I get an error

For the FileAssetid I tried this regex:

```
regex = re.compile(r"([0-9a-f]{8})\S*-\S*([0-9a-f]{4})\S*-\S*([0-9a-f]{4})\S*-\S*([0-9a-f]{4})\S*-\S*([0-9a-f]{12})")
```

But i get the following 034b9317‌​, 60d9, 45c2, b6d6, 0f24‌​b59e1991

Im not to sure how to get the data as its displayed.

Comment: can you put some data of your file here?

Comment: The text shows up like this: 

{"d":{"__type":"WikiFileNodeContent:http:\/\/samplesite.com.au\/ns\/business\/wiki","author":null,"description":null,"fileAssetId":"034b9317-60d9-45c2-b6d6-0f24b59e1991","filename":"Reports.pdf"},"createdBy":1531,"createdByUsername":"John Cash","icon":"\/Assets10.37.5.0\/pix\/16x16\/page_white_acrobat.png","id":3041,"inheritedPermissions":false,"name":"map","permissions":[23,87,35,49,65],"type":3,"viewLevel":2},{"__type":"WikiNode:http:\/\/samplesite.com.au\/ns\/business\/wiki","children":[],"content":

I am wanting to get the "fileAssetId" and filename"

Comment: the dictionary is not completed. You are missgin `[` at the beginning and `}]` and the end

Comment: I would love to extract the value after "fileAssetId": and the value after the filename, but I'm not to sure how to do it.

Comment: Using a JSON parser must be a better option?

Comment: If you have an example I am more than happy to try it, everything ive tried I get KeyError: 'filename'

Comment: You should describe the error when you tried to use json.loads. It is probably more robust to fix that error than using a regex...

Comment: I tried the following:

import re
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_data=open('jsonfile').read()

data = json.loads(json_data)
pprint(data)

Everything prints like:  u'id': 204, line by line, but if i try to define keys that where i run into trouble: import re
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_data=open('jsonfile').read()

data = json.loads(json_data)
data["filename"][0]
pprint (data)

Comment: if i try 

with open('jsonfile', 'r') as f:
    distros_dict = json.load(f)

for distro in distros_dict:
    print(distro['filename'])

the Error is 'TypeError: string indices must be integers'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using positive lookahead and lookbehind:

```
(?<=\"fileAssetId\":\")[a-fA-F0-9-]+?(?=\")
```

captures the `fileAssetId` and

```
(?<=\"filename\":\").+?(?=\")
```

matches the filename.

For a detailed explanation of the regex have a look at the [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0OhB7x/1/)-Example. (Note: I combined both in the example with an OR-Operator | to show both matches at once)

To get a list of all matches use `re.findall` or `re.finditer` instead of `re.match`.

`re.findall(pattern, string)` returns a list of matching strings.

`re.finditer(pattern, string)` returns an iterator with the objects.

Comment: That works, thank you so much, but its only showing the first, not all the values, im doing it this way: 

import re
f=open("jsonfile.txt")
f=f.readlines()
for line in f:
    m = re.search(r'(?<=\"fileAssetId\":\")[a-fA-F0-9-]+?(?=\")|(?<=\"filename\":\").+?(?=\")', line)
    print m.group()

Comment: As i said in my answer edit, use findall or finditer not search.

Comment: That works a treat, thank you. Is there a way i could store all the values for "filename" and "fileAssetId" so i could do something like 
wget = urllib.urlopen('http://samplewebsite.com' + fileAssetId_value + filename_value) ??? Thank you for your help.

Comment: If one asset id is always associated with one filename, I would try to fix your json data and load it instead of using regex as it'll be a very complex regex to get the associated values. Can you do `with open('jsonfile', 'r') as f: distros_dict = json.load(f) for distro in distros_dict: print(distro)` and share the output? Then I can maybe tell you why you can't access the filename.

Comment: Output for your code loading it as a JSON file was just the letter
d

Comment: Assuming that the asset id is always before the filename in the String you can get tuples with this regex: `((?<=\"fileAssetId\":\")[a-fA-F0-9-]+?(?=\")).+?((?<=\"filename\":\").+?(?=\"))` which would yield a list like this `[('034b9317-60d9-45c2-b6d6-0f24b59e1991', 'Reports.pdf'), ('034b9317-60d9-45c2-b6d6-0f24b5a23491', 'Reports2.pdf')]`

Comment: That works. I'll see how I go trying to get individual values and create an address from them, thank you so much for all your assistance, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Your welcome. Please accept my answer if it helped you and solved the problem you asked for.

Comment: Will do, any tips for how to group the values together so the filename + fileAttributeId. The other option ive thought about was export them to a csv file and starting a new file to grab row1 and row2 assigning them values. i'll research it, I just thought id ask :) - am still learning Python.

Comment: Just research a little bit about string formatting yourself and I bet you'll find a good way to format your url.

Comment: Thanks once again I appreciate it

Comment: Complete regex and CSV export is (?<=\"fileAssetId\":\")[a-fA-F0-9-]+?(?=\")|(?<=\"filename\":\").+?(?=\")|(?<=\"id\":)[a-fA-F0-9-]+?(?=\,). with open('file.csv', 'wt') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(pattern_name) - Thank you Igle. Progressing slowly

Comment: Okay I'm stuck, I want to put the information in Columns in an excel file, so
fileAssetId     Filename    Id
the found FileAssettID in one column. the filename in another column and id in the next in order... etc I've also discovered Id shows up on other objects so i need Id only to show up AFTER filename has been found, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's [walk method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) and check each entry with [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match).

In case that the string you got is not convertable to a python dict, you can use just regex:

```
print re.match(r'.*fileAssetId\":\"([^\"]+)\".*', your_pattern).group(1)
```

Solution for your example:

```
import re

example_string = '{"d":{"__type":"WikiFileNodeContent:http:\/\/samplesite.com.u\/ns\/business\/wiki","author":null,"description":null,"fileAssetId":"034b9317-60d9-45c2-b6d6-0f24b59e1991","filename":"Reports.pdf"},"createdBy":1531,"createdByUsername":"John Cash","icon":"\/Assets10.37.5.0\/pix\/16x16\/page_white_acrobat.png","id":3041,"inheritedPermissions":false,"name":"map","permissions":[23,87,35,49,65],"type":3,"viewLevel":2},{"__type":"WikiNode:http:\/\/samplesite.com.au\/ns\/business\/wiki","children":[],"content"'

regex_pattern = r'.*fileAssetId\":\"([^\"]+)\".*'
match = re.match(regex_pattern, example_string)
fileAssetId = match.group(1)
print('fileAssetId: {}'.format(fileAssetId))
```

executing this yields:

```
34b9317‌​-60d9-45c2-b6d6-0f24‌​b59e1991
```

Comment: coming up red in sublime text \":\"([^\"]+)\".*`).group(1)

Comment: File "test2.py", line 18
    fileAsset = re.match(r`.*fileAssetId\":\"([^\"]+)\".*`, regex).group(1)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: you are missing `'`

Comment: Thank you, that's better but errors out. 
return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: As a one complete regex request, i get:     
fileAsset = re.match(r'.*fileAssetId\":\"([^\"]+)\".*', r"([0-9a-f]{8})\S*-\S*([0-9a-f]{4})\S*-\S*([0-9a-f]{4})\S*-\S*([0-9a-f]{4})\S*-\S*([0-9a-f]{12})").group(1)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: read a bit the docu! .. you don't need `r` infront of you string. You got the AttributeError because it was not match. Try pages like http://regex101.com/ to fine-tune your regular expression

Comment: Removing the r gives SyntaxError: invalid syntax. I used the regex101, removed \S* as it looks like that wasn't required, but, i cant remove the r.

Comment: in my example, your_pattern is the string you received. the one you want to look at. This is the second argument in `re.match`. The first one is the regular expression

Comment: so what would i define 'your_pattern" as if not a pattern of the regular expression?

Comment: regex = re.compile(r"([0-9a-f]{8})-([0-9a-f]{4})-([0-9a-f]{4})-([0-9a-f]{4})-([0-9a-f]{12})")
fileAsset = re.match(r'.*fileAssetId\":\"([^\"]+)\".*', regex).group(1)

That is how i have it layed out, i used the editor online - it doesnt like your .*fileAssetId\":\"([^\"]+)\".*'

Comment: Your example works, even with the text file, but its only showing one result, how could I loop if to search for all the 'fileAttributes"?

Comment: do it bit of research and don't expect SO to write your code ;)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python

Comment: give it an up vote, if you think it was helpful. And mark it as correct if you think it was the correct answer. thanks ;)

Comment: what if fileAssetId has a number (integer or float) instead of string?

Comment: @KhaledAhmedSobhy `[^\"]+` matches at least one character that is not `"`, so int and float will be matched as well. Though, you might want to cast it to an int or float once matched.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding \n to the string that you are entering in to the file (\n means new line)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the idea given here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845829 and by following the JSON standard https://www.json.org/json-en.html, we can use Python + regex https://pypi.org/project/regex/ and do the following:

```
json_pattern = (
    r'(?(DEFINE)'
    r'(?P<whitespace>( |\n|\r|\t)*)'
    r'(?P<boolean>true|false)'
    r'(?P<number>-?(0|([1-9]\d*))(\.\d*[1-9])?([eE][+-]?\d+)?)'
    r'(?P<string>"([^"\\]|\\("|\\|/|b|f|n|r|t|u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}))*")'
    r'(?P<array>\[((?&whitespace)|(?&value)(,(?&value))*)\])'
    r'(?P<key>(?&whitespace)(?&string)(?&whitespace))'
    r'(?P<value>(?&whitespace)((?&boolean)|(?&number)|(?&string)|(?&array)|(? &object)|null)(?&whitespace))'
    r'(?P<object>\{((?&whitespace)|(?&key):(?&value)(,(?&key):(?&value))*)\})'
    r'(?P<document>(?&object)|(?&array))'
    r')'
    r'(?&document)'
)

json_regex = regex.compile(json_pattern)

match = json_regex.match(json_document_text)
```

You can change last line in `json_pattern` to match not document but individual objects replacing `(?&document)` by `(?&object)`. I think the regex is easier than I expected, but I did not run extensive tests on this. It works fine for me and I have tested hundreds of files. I wil try to improve my answer in case I find any issue when running it.