# Python read from API and write to an array/list

Tags: python, arrays, api

Am able to read from API and write to a list but this is in this format:
('AAA','FF','LL')
('BBB','SS','DD')

Can how can I iterate nested to get the information from first row as AAA, FF,LL individually.

Thank you.
AJ

Answer (score 0):

[Python - Parsing JSON formatted text file with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47454689/python-parsing-json-formatted-text-file-with-regex)

This answer will help you to process your input data. I'd suggest the following code structure. I'll provide some pseudo-code:

```
list1
for item in APIInput:
    //Find each element in item by dividing the string on commas, remove ( and '
    //take each element and put it into another list (list2)
    //Add that list (list2) to list1
```

RegEx is very powerful for this type of work.

Comment: try this: `for item in YourList: print item`

Comment: I get output as ('AAA','FF',LL)

Comment: Are you putting each element of the API return into a list? Or are you doing something like this? `variable = APIList[1]` I'd suggest using RegEx to parse your input

Comment: print item gives output as
('apple', 'Fruit','red')
('orange', 'Fruit','orange')
('Cucumber', 'Veggie', 'green')

Comment: from API am getting the response data. data = response.json()

Comment: It seems that you aren't parsing each individual item. I can't write the algorithm for you but i'll post another answer below linking you to some good information