# How to Get Span Id of Same Words in one String?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**In this problem,I used Search Function in Re Module of Python but I'm Able to get the Span ID of the First Word Only**

```
string2="Jhon is a good boy,Jhon is brilliant,Jhon is a data scientist,Jhon is Jhon"
m=re.search("Jhon",string2)
print(m)
```

**I'm Getting Output Like This**

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='Jhon'>
```

**This output(Span ID) is only for the first word,Please Tell Me Is there any way to find Span ID for All "Jhon"**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python ?

Comment: Good enough.... use `re.finditer`.

Comment: No it is not helpful to get the span id, <callable_iterator object at 0x03EAE970>