# regex python group overwrite

Tags: python, regex

the string is 'POSIX TAR ARCHIVE (GNU)'
the regex pattern '(TAR)|(POSIX)'

python code :

```
import re 
pattern = '(TAR)|(POSIX)'
string = 'POSIX TAR ARCHIVE (GNU)'
match = re.search(pattern, string , re.IGNORECASE)
match.groups()
```

the result is only POSIX not tar
why??

Comment: Use `re.findall` to get multiple matches. And use `'TAR|POSIX'`. `print(re.findall(r'TAR|POSIX', s))`

Comment: Dupe of [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
re.findall(pattern, string, re.IGNORECASE)
```

[re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#finding-all-adverbs) matches all the patterns you are looking for, 
while [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match) finds and returns the first match from the string.

Comment: Please update your answer with a bit of explanation about why you need to use `findall` in this case.