# regex to find words in a sentence with no repeated consecutive characters

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a regex pattern to filter out words in a sentence with no repeated consecutive characters.

I have tried `r'(?!.*(\w)\1{3,}).+'` as the regex pattern but it doesn't work.

for instance, in the sentence 'mike is amaaazing', I want the regex pattern to pick up 'mike' and 'is' only.

Any ideas?

Comment: how about string like, `hahahaha` should it match ?

Comment: Use `\w` instead of the dots and limit your quantifier to 2 ( 2 + captured letter = 3)

Comment: ```hahaha``` is fine

Comment: you want to extract words that don't have 3 repeated letters?

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a word-boundary at the beginning and replace the dot with `\w` to be sure your lookahead doesn't go out of the tested word.

```
>>> s = 'mike is amaaazing'
>>> [m[1] for m in re.findall(r'\b(?!\w*?(\w)\1)(\w+)', s)]
['mike', 'is']
```

Since `re.findall` returns only capture groups when defined in the pattern, you can use a list comprehension to extract the second capture group (in which is the whole word).

Comment: what should I use as token_pattern in countvectorizer if I want to filter out words with repeated consecutive characters?

Comment: @Sina: I really don't know, but perhaps you can grab all words and filter them in a second time with something like re.match.

Comment: I might be wrong, but there is a quantifier `{3,}` in the OP's pattern. Perhaps to do match for example `meeting` and not `amaaazing` you could make it `\1{2,}` 1+ though.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: I don't know: there's the question title and something else in the question body. But actually the problem isn't here for Sina.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this

```
\b(?:(\w)(?!\1))+\b
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/WGLCde/1/)

Comment: @Sina it matches only what you're said in question. can you elaborate what is not working ? rule which is not followed ?

Comment: when I try it on ```string='mike is amaaaazing'``` and ```pattern=r'\b(?:(\w)(?!\1))+\b'```, then ```re.findall(pattern,string)``` returns ```[e,s]```

Comment: @Sina: `re.findall` returns only the captures if defined, otherwise it returns the whole match.

Comment: i wanna use it with re.findall...so what should be the pattern?

Comment: @Sina you `finditer`, [`How can i find all the matches`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python)

Comment: I also want to use this pattern in countvectorizer as token_pattern, and the pattern you provided doesn't do the job

Comment: for instance, I don't want countvectorizer to pick up 'aaaaa' in a sentence